# How can I extract the main text of a webpage using WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, web-scraping, wkwebview

I want to extract the main text from a given website.  So far, I did it by using WKWebView and evaluateJavaScript- but it somehow doesn't work with websites like [the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/11/world/middleeast/syria-torture-prisons.html) or [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/stories-47675301?utm_source=pocket-newtab) despite having easy to extract paragraph tags in HTML. What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

This is the code I am using so far:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
{
        webView.stopLoading()
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerText", completionHandler:
        { result, error in
            if let userAgent = result as? String
            {
                print(userAgent)
            }
        })
}
```

For instance, the New York Times article output only gives:

```swift
SKIP TO CONTENTSKIP TO SITE INDEX

Image
CreditCredit



Image
Image
Image
Access more of The Times by creating a free account or logging in.
Access more for free.

Site Index
Site Information Navigation
```

Comment: This is a really hard problem. Websites have incredibly varied layouts. I wonder if there's a library that does this, or at least a reference implementation. Safari has a page reader that must have implemented something like this. IDK if it's implemented within Safari or WebKit, but if it's the latter, you can look at their implementation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used SwiftSoup before but because (as you said) there are so many different ways of building a website the library didn't always scrape correctly if the webpage I am trying to do it on didn't have a paragraph tag.